# How can I create a global object/service that can be used across my Viewmodels/controllers android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an app that is powered by firebase. I want to implement the firebase auth, which according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) would require me to initialize the auth object and use it around the application:

```
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
// ...
// Initialize Firebase Auth
auth = Firebase.auth
```

Is there a way to have the initialized auth object global, and probably lifecycle aware, so I can just use it anywhere I want across my app?

Please note I am new to android development/kotlin

Comment: What do you mean by "lifecycle aware"? Which lifecycle should the object follow given that it is global?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do it. With Hilt you can provide it

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AuthModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth =  Firebase.auth
```

And in your Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SignUpActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
...
```

Comment: Nice, is there a non-dependency injection way and can making it a lifecycle component also work?

Comment: You can access `Firebase.auth` from wherever you need it like in the documentation you linked Google does it in EmailPasswordActivity